# How to bind a button with a key in netbeans designer

Tags: java, netbeans

Is there a way in the netbeans designer to bind a jbutton with for example the enter button? I know how to code it but netbeans won't let me edit the code it generated.

Kind regards,

Comment: You want to attach an ActionListener to the button?

Answer (score 2):

Select the component(jButton), go to the **Properties** window and select the **Code tab**. and **Custom Creation Code** that's it..

Comment: Thanks. Found also a way to do it via the designer, right click on the field then events and select key :-) then you can do just the same thing. Thanks anyway for the custom advise.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at KeyBindings.

Here's a link.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html